# Remove object with given property from JSON using regex

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Given I have a string which represents JSON object. It might be **invalid**, as there might be some params which will be replaced by another system (e.g. %param%). I need to remove all objects with known propertyName equal to "true" using **regex**.

```
{
    "someTopLevelProp": "value",
    "arrayOfData": [
        {
            "firstPropIAlwaysKnow": "value",
            "dontCareProp": $paramValue$,
            "dontCareProp2": 2,
            "flagWhichShouldIUse": true,
            "somethingAtTheEnd": "value"
        },
        {
            "absolutelyAnotherObject": %paramValue%
        },
        {
            "firstPropIAlwaysKnow": "value",
            "dontCareProp": "value",
            "dontCareProp2": 2,
            "flagWhichShouldIUse": false,
            "somethingAtTheEnd": "value"
        },
        {
            "firstPropIAlwaysKnow": "value",
            "dontCareProp": "value",
            "dontCareProp2": 2,
            "flagWhichShouldIUse": true,
            "somethingAtTheEnd": "value"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the example above, I always have "**firstPropIAlwaysKnow**" which means that object can contain flag which I need. After that there might be other properties. But the most important here is "**flagWhichShouldIUse**" prop, which mean this object should be removed (but only in case when value equal to 'true'). As result I should receive:

```
{
    "someTopLevelProp": "value",
    "arrayOfData": [
        {
            "absolutelyAnotherObject": %paramValue%
        },
        {
            "firstPropIAlwaysKnow": "value",
            "dontCareProp": "value",
            "dontCareProp2": 2,
            "flagWhichShouldIUse": false,
            "somethingAtTheEnd": "value"
        }
    ]
}
```

My knowledge in regex are not strong enough, thus kindly ask for community's help.

P.S. Please do not mention that parsing JSON with regex it's crazy\incorrect\bad idea - be sure I know that.

**ANSWER:** now I have working regex which do that stuff. Thank you everyone who tried to help here. Maybe it will be useful for someone.

```
/{\s+?"firstPropIAlwaysKnow": "value"[^{}]+?(?:\{[^}]*\}[^}]+?)*[^}]+?"flagWhichShouldIUse": true[^}]+?},?/gi
```

[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%7B%5Cs%2B%3F%22firstPropIAlwaysKnow%22%3A%20%22value%22%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%3F(%3F%3A%5C%7B%5B%5E%7D%5D*%5C%7D%5B%5E%7D%5D%2B%3F)*%5B%5E%7D%5D%2B%3F%22flagWhichShouldIUse%22%3A%20true%5B%5E%7D%5D%2B%3F%7D%2C%3F)

Comment: Doubt this is actually possible without writing your own JSON parser that is aware of the particular syntax that would cause `JSON.parse` to throw. The biggest problem is the nesting.

Comment: Are the probably-invalid parts well-defined? I mean for example if you know that any kind of invalid stuff comes from a `%...%` expression inside the json as value of some property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really can't do this with just regular expressions. Something like this might work:

```
let filtered = jsonstring
  // split into the individual 'objects'
  // might need to modify this depending on formatting. You
  // could use something like /},\s*{/ to split the string,
  // but couldn't re-join with same formatting
  .split('},{')
  // filter for only the strings with the relevant property
  // set to false
  .filter(s => s.match(/"flagWhichShouldIUse":\s*false/) // again, may need to change
   // put humpty-dumpty back together again
  .join('},{');
```

The exact splitting method will depend heavily on the structure of your JSON, and this isn't fool-proof. It doesn't handle nesting properly. If your JSON is pretty-printed, you could use the number of tab/space characters as part of the splitter: this for instance would only split for one tab only: `/\n\t},\s*{/`

Comment: Quite interesting idea, and probably more stable.

Comment: @kirill.buga yes, and also less work than writing a custom json parser grammar :)

Comment: I'm also thinking about commas at the beginning\end of the object.